# SMS gateway with a "from" parameter

Tags: gateway, sms

I am programming a mobile app which send sms. I need a gateway that let me put a "from" parameter. On many gateways, I can only subscribe, put my mobile phone number as the sender after a verification process.
The main problem is that the phone number verification is only available for my and not for my users.
My customers can send an sms but the receiver does not see their mobile phone number in the "from" field.

Do you know a good gateway which support that (in an automated way) ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to ensure that this service is enabled by your chosen telco provider as well (if your gateway gives you a choice). We wanted to do this about 3 years ago (in Australia) and Vodafone were the only company that even knew what we were talking about!

Answer (score 1):

we use [cardboardfish](http://www.cardboardfish.com/), setting a from number is a matter of giving an extra parameter when POSTing to their HTTPSMS service URL

Answer (score 1):

MX Telecom lets you do that: http://www.mxtelecom.com/tech/sms/http/send

Answer (score 0):

"from" or "caller id" is supported with many providers.

However, when the provider re-transmit the SMS, sometimes this field is lost.

In some countries there are regulations and local GSM providers remove the field as well.

For example in South Africa you can use text like "NIKI", you can use long phone number like "+491234512345", but you can not use short phone number like "1234".

Disclamer: I am working for SMS provider and on some routes, we support "from":
http://gate.quadra-mm.com/

---

### Update:

You need to choose a provider and then test for specific country / GSM network you need to send SMS-es to.

Most of the providers will give you small test credit or will send test SMS-es.